# Get Jekyll collection item name (HRU)

Tags: collections, jekyll

I'm making a Jekyll site destinated for GitHub Pages, and pre-testing it on local Windows 8.1 PC with Jekyll 2.5.3, Ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x64-mingw32] and Gem 2.0.14.

In Jekyll, I have a collection named `albums`.

Directory structure for `_albums` is similar to the following:

```
_albums
    foo.md
    bar.md
    baz.md
```

Each file has Front Matter containing values such as `title`, `description` etc.

In some site page I'm making a Liquid loop such as following:

```
{% for album in site.albums %}
    /* need to get album name here */
{% endfor %}
```

**The question is**:

How can I get a *bare name* for collection item — like `foo` or `bar` (without extension, containing folders etc.)

[Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) says something about `name` variable, but `album` variable only has following properties: `output`, `content`, `path`, `relative_path`, `url`, `collection` (and also `title` and `description` I set in Front Matter)

`album.path` has value similar to: `d:/repo/<project_name>/_albums/foo.md`

**A workaround I use for now is:**

```
{% assign album_name = album.path | split:"/" | last | split:"." | first %}
```

Could you please suggest *any better way?*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your workaround is ok.
I think that there is an error in Jekyll documentation.