# An elegant way to get Jekyll collection item by name?

Tags: collections, jekyll

In Jekyll 2.5.3, I use `albums` [collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) (because I need not only data stored, but also pages generated).

When Jekyll [Data Files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) are used, you can get a data for particular item as simple as: `site.data.albums[foo]`

But with collections, things are much worse. All those ways I've tried just do nothing:

- `site.albums[foo]`
- `site.collections.albums[foo]`
- `site.collections.albums.docs[foo]`
- `site.collections.albums.files[foo]`

So I need to:

1. Loop through all collection items
2. For each of them [get a bare name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963826/get-jekyll-collection-item-name-hru)
3. Compare this name with some target name
4. If the name matches, finally assign collection item data to some variable to use

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

[As of Jekyll 3.2](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2016/07/26/jekyll-3-2-0-released/), you can use the filter `where_exp` to filter a collection by any of its properties. So if I have the following item in an `albums` collection:

```
---
title: My Amazing Album
---
...
```

I can grab the first match for an item by that name:

```
{% assign album = site.albums 
    | where_exp:"album", "album.title == 'My Amazing Album'" 
    | first %}
```

Note that I use the `first` filter because `where_exp` returns an array of matched items.

And then use it any way I like:

```
<h1>{{ album.title }}</h1>
```

I can't vouch for the build performance of this method, but I have to imagine it's better than a Liquid loop.

Answer (score 4):

I have just done this today, you are correct with your assertions. Here's how I did it:

```
<!-- this is in a partial with a 'name' parameter -->
{% for item in site.albums %}
    {% assign name = item.path | split:"/" | last | split:"." | first %}
    {% if name == include.name %}
        {% assign collectionItem = item %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Usage**

```
{{ collectionItem.title }}
{{ collectionItem.url }}
{{ collectionItem.path }}
```

It can even be used to populate values in other partials, like so:

```
{% include card.html title=workItem.title bg=workItem.card.bg href=workItem.url %}
```

Comment: This is going to kill build time. Too bad there isn't a better way.